# How to change the color of a text-decoration on highlight/selected text

Tags: css, sass

I've changed the color of my text when it's highlighted/selected, but I've just noticed that text-decorations are still black.

I added `text-decoration-color: #fff` to my `::selection` css but it didn't take effect, does it need to be done another way?

My CSS is:

```
::-moz-selection {
  background: rgba($colorRed, .85);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration-color: #fff;
}

::selection {
  background: rgba($colorRed, .85);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Check your page in Firefox

Comment: Hmm nope, still black in Firefox too

Comment: Are you using php?

Comment: Nah, just SCSS.

Comment: ok, I edited your tag

Comment: Did you tried using this too  -moz-text-decoration-color

Comment: I hadn't but adding it made no difference.

Comment: Please tell me what kind of change you need on selection ? color change, underline, ?

Comment: So it's the underline that's causing the issue. I've also changed the text color and background but those two are fine

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/g4b1yi) of the affected text. I can't link to the website though I'm afraid as it's signed under an NDA.

Comment: I've added a code snippet to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, I slightly edited it to reflect the inline style of my underline.

Comment: If you don't get what's wrong just look at [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqoPRr): the underline doesn't work on selection!

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not trying to add an underline to the selected text, merely change the color of the underline that was already there.

Comment: Use a border-bottom instead of text decoration

Answer (score 3):

The text decoration will only work if is already styling an element.

`text-decoration`, on `::selection` will only work on elements that have the same decoration properties set already.

```css
p{
text-decoration:underline overline transparent;
}

::selection{
text-decoration: underline overline red;
background:green;
}
```

```html
<p> SELECTED TEXT WILL DIFFER THAN UNSELECTED BE UNDERLINED</p>
```

`text-decoration` on selection is [possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection)

Comment: Interestingly, the MDN page indicates full support in Firefox, but I can only make this work in Chrome. In Firefox 94, the underline/overline colors are not changed in selected text.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but changing `text-decoration-color` within a `::selection` selector is not possible. Only color, background, cursor, and outline can be styled.

During my research I could not figure out how to apply outline styles on selection, but that was not your problem anyway [W3C Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The `text-decoration-color` on the `::selection` has no effect because there is no corresponding `text-decoration-line` inside the `::selection`, at least in Chromium based browsers. Redefine all the `text-decoration` properties inside the `::selection`, not just the color.

```scss
::selection{
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  background: rgba($colorRed, .85);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration-color: #fff;
}
```

Cross browser support is in flux at the moment, but the spec is in place to get consistent behavior. `::selection` will support text decorations and colors, and maybe shadows. Not outline, cursor, or anything else at the time of writing.